# Using std::move

Tags: c++, c++11

Before `C++11` I have used swap-to-back to avoid deep copy overheads, like:

```
vector<vector<Object> > Objects;

for(/* some range */)
{
    vector<Object> v;
    for(/* some other range */)
    {
        v.push_back(/* some object */);
    }
    Objects.push_back(vector<Object>());
    Objects.back().swap(v);
}
```

How can I use `std::move` to move `v` into `Objects` to avoid deep copy overhead instead of `swap`?
I know there are a lot of workarounds here like multi arrays or just inserting directly into `Objects.back()`, but I need an example of usage of `std::move` to understand it.

Comment: Why do you create `v` at all? Why not just add a blank vector into Objects and then `Objects.back().push_back()` into it? That removes even more overhead while being simpler.

Comment: @Ayjay: read the rest of the question

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
vector<vector<Object> > Objects;

for(/* some range */)
{
    vector<Object> v;
    for(/* some other range */)
    {
        v.push_back(/* some object */);
    }
    Objects.push_back(std::move(v));
}
```

Comment: But that leaves `v` behind. I understood that `std::move` should be somewhat destructive.

Comment: @Dani: Don't assume. Try it. Actually, reading the source for `vector::vector(vector&&)` would be enough as well. The semantics are eerily close to your `std::swap` version - but more elegant and possibly more efficient in the general case

Comment: Definitely more efficient if `Object`'s default constructor is non-trivial.

Comment: @sehe: generally my objects have trivial constructors. to avoid problem with non trivial constructors/destructors this might bring, I always use pointers when I use objects with non trivial constructors.

Comment: @Dani after moving, `v` is left in an unspecified (but still valid) state. That's the "somewhat destructive" part. It means you can reuse it, but you have no guarantees about its current value (assigning or clearing it is fine, but size() could return anything). In this case, it's probably left empty.

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes: unspecified but valid state means I must go through every possible state, check for it, and revert it to a state I want it in. thats way too close to undefined behavior for me.

Comment: @Dani:  What are you wanting to do with `v` after the `move` shown in sehe's code above?  All he does is destruct it.  Since `~vector<Object>()` has no preconditions, a destruction after `move` is perfectly fine.  Is there something else you would like to do?  If so you could put it into a known state with something as simple as `v.clear()` (`vector<Object>::clear()` also has no preconditions and so may be called after a `move`).

Comment: @Dani: "But that leaves v behind. I understood that std::move should be somewhat destructive." - Any time you use std::move meaningfully, you leave the variable in question behind. Its entire purpose is to cast something that isn't a rvalue into a rvalue. And no, it isn't destructive in any way, being just a cast. (But the purpose of the cast is to allow some function to "destroy" the passed object.)

Answer (score 17):

```
Objects.push_back( std::move( v ) );
```

Comment: +1 for having the correct answer and getting a lot less attention